# Stack corruption detected, dalvik VM crash

Tags: android, dalvik

I have a tracker application running on android tablet. I notice that somehow some of the tablets reboots themselves from time to time.

When i investigate the issue  find out that i get "stack corruption detected" error then few miliseconds later android VM crashes.

These crashes occur every 5 minutes to 20 minutes there is no pattern other then tracker app running and using GPS and 3G.

These tablets run android 4.2.2 and this is their latest update from Samsung sadly.

There is no mention of my apk in the logs, and my application is pure java. What exactly is causing the issue and how can i fix it?

Below is the logcat output:

```
05-11 15:33:16.084: A/<unknown>(30963): stack corruption detected: aborted
05-11 15:33:16.116: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'bluetooth_manager' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'bluetooth_secure_mode_manager' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'input_method' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'accessibility' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'meminfo' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'DirEncryptService' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'container_service' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'audio' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'wallpaper' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'display' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'power' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'activity' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'CustomFrequencyManagerService' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'gfxinfo' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'usagestats' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'content' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'log_manager_service' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'cpuinfo' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'account' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'telephony.registry' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'battery' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'entropy' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'mount' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'sensorservice' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'dbinfo' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'vibrator' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'mdm.remotedesktop' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'alarm' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'scheduling_policy' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'hardware' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'user' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'permission' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'batteryinfo' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'edmnativehelper' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'harmony_eas_service' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'enterprise_policy' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'remoteinjection' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'clipboard' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'clipboardEx' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'netstats' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'textservices' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'statusbar' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'application_policy' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'wifi_policy' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'package' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'phone_restriction_policy' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'network_management' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'enterprise_license_policy' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'window' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'input' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'netpolicy' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'multiwindow' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'wifip2p' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'sec_analytics' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'wifi' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'wfd' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'notification' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'dropbox' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'devicestoragemonitor' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'search' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'country_detector' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'location' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'updatelock' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'throttle' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'servicediscovery' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'connectivity' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'lock_settings' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'device_policy' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'usb' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'serial' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'uimode' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'backup' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'appwidget' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'diskstats' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'AtCmdFwd' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'samplingprofiler' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'commontime_management' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'motion_recognition' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'voip' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'dreams' died
05-11 15:33:16.155: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'license_log_service' died
05-11 15:33:16.162: W/AudioFlinger(30688): power manager service died !!!
05-11 15:33:16.170: I/audio_policy_mrvl(30688): mrvl_ap_dev_release_output: 2 (hardware output)
05-11 15:33:16.170: I/audio_policy_mrvl(30688): mrvl_ap_dev_release_output: 2 (hardware output)
05-11 15:33:16.178: W/Sensors(31110): sensorservice died [0x5d194240]
05-11 15:33:16.178: W/Sensors(31315): sensorservice died [0x5d1b4d70]
05-11 15:33:16.178: W/Sensors(31217): sensorservice died [0x5bab4fa0]
05-11 15:33:16.178: W/Sensors(31204): sensorservice died [0x5d1ae190]
05-11 15:33:16.178: W/Sensors(2742): sensorservice died [0x5d13c0e8]
05-11 15:33:16.186: D/SurfaceFlinger(111): Screen acquired, type=0 flinger=0x405083c8
05-11 15:33:16.186: D/SurfaceFlinger(111):  screen was previously acquired
05-11 15:33:16.373: D/AndroidRuntime(31204): Shutting down VM
05-11 15:33:16.373: W/dalvikvm(31204): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40dee930)
05-11 15:33:16.420: E/AndroidRuntime(31204): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-11 15:33:16.420: E/AndroidRuntime(31204): java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.DeadObjectException
05-11 15:33:16.420: E/AndroidRuntime(31204):    at android.net.TrafficStats.getMobileIfaces(TrafficStats.java:641)
05-11 15:33:16.420: E/AndroidRuntime(31204):    at android.net.TrafficStats.getMobileTxPackets(TrafficStats.java:270)
05-11 15:33:16.420: E/AndroidRuntime(31204):    at com.android.internal.telephony.DataConnectionTracker$TxRxSum.updateTxRxSum(DataConnectionTracker.java:510)
05-11 15:33:16.420: E/AndroidRuntime(31204):    at com.android.internal.telephony.DataConnectionTracker.updateDataActivity(DataConnectionTracker.java:1566)
05-11 15:33:16.420: E/AndroidRuntime(31204):    at com.android.internal.telephony.DataConnectionTracker$2.run(DataConnectionTracker.java:431)
05-11 15:33:16.420: E/AndroidRuntime(31204):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
05-11 15:33:16.420: E/AndroidRuntime(31204):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-11 15:33:16.420: E/AndroidRuntime(31204):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
05-11 15:33:16.420: E/AndroidRuntime(31204):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5365)
05-11 15:33:16.420: E/AndroidRuntime(31204):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-11 15:33:16.420: E/AndroidRuntime(31204):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-11 15:33:16.420: E/AndroidRuntime(31204):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
05-11 15:33:16.420: E/AndroidRuntime(31204):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
05-11 15:33:16.420: E/AndroidRuntime(31204):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-11 15:33:16.420: E/AndroidRuntime(31204): Caused by: android.os.DeadObjectException
05-11 15:33:16.420: E/AndroidRuntime(31204):    at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
05-11 15:33:16.420: E/AndroidRuntime(31204):    at android.net.INetworkStatsService$Stub$Proxy.getMobileIfaces(INetworkStatsService.java:232)
05-11 15:33:16.420: E/AndroidRuntime(31204):    at android.net.TrafficStats.getMobileIfaces(TrafficStats.java:639)
05-11 15:33:16.420: E/AndroidRuntime(31204):    ... 13 more
05-11 15:33:16.452: E/installd(116): eof
05-11 15:33:16.452: E/installd(116): failed to read size
05-11 15:33:16.452: I/installd(116): closing connection
05-11 15:33:16.452: I/Process(31204): Sending signal. PID: 31204 SIG: 9
05-11 15:33:16.452: E/AndroidRuntime(31204): Error reporting crash
05-11 15:33:16.452: E/AndroidRuntime(31204): android.os.DeadObjectException
05-11 15:33:16.452: E/AndroidRuntime(31204):    at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
05-11 15:33:16.452: E/AndroidRuntime(31204):    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.handleApplicationCrash(ActivityManagerNative.java:3624)
05-11 15:33:16.452: E/AndroidRuntime(31204):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:138)
05-11 15:33:16.452: E/AndroidRuntime(31204):    at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
05-11 15:33:16.452: E/AndroidRuntime(31204):    at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
05-11 15:33:16.452: E/AndroidRuntime(31204):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-11 15:33:16.467: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'phone' died
05-11 15:33:16.467: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'isms' died
05-11 15:33:16.467: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'phoneext' died
05-11 15:33:16.467: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'iphonesubinfo' died
05-11 15:33:16.467: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'sip' died
05-11 15:33:16.467: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'simphonebook' died
05-11 15:33:16.467: I/audio_policy_mrvl(30688): mrvl_ap_dev_release_output: 2 (hardware output)
05-11 15:33:16.608: I/BootAnimation(6191): ret=2, fps:12, interval:83333
05-11 15:33:16.639: I/BootAnimation(6191): createSurface RGB565
05-11 15:33:16.639: E/BootAnimation(6191): /sys/class/sec/led/led_pattern: open error, fd = -1
05-11 15:33:16.639: W/BootAnimation(6191): resolution w=600, h=1024
05-11 15:33:16.639: W/BootAnimation(6191): original qmg w=600, h=1024
05-11 15:33:17.233: E/InputEventReceiver(31217): channel ~ Publisher closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
05-11 15:33:17.444: E/InputEventReceiver(31110): channel ~ Publisher closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
05-11 15:33:17.444: E/Sensors(31315): SensorEventQueue::waitForEvent error HANGUP
05-11 15:33:17.444: E/InputEventReceiver(835): channel ~ Publisher closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
05-11 15:33:17.452: E/InputEventReceiver(31110): channel ~ Publisher closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
05-11 15:33:17.452: E/InputEventReceiver(835): channel ~ Publisher closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
05-11 15:33:17.452: E/InputEventReceiver(835): channel ~ Publisher closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
05-11 15:33:17.452: E/InputEventReceiver(835): channel ~ Publisher closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
05-11 15:33:17.452: D/Zygote(30691): Process 30963 terminated by signal (6)
05-11 15:33:17.452: I/Zygote(30691): Exit zygote because system server (30963) has terminated
05-11 15:33:17.616: I/Netd(6197): Netd 1.0 starting
05-11 15:33:17.623: W/InterfaceController(6197): Warning (Cannot load library: load_library(linker.cpp:745): library "/system/lib/libnetcmdiface.so" not found) while opening the net interface command library
05-11 15:33:17.772: E/SMD(107): DCD OFF
05-11 15:33:17.928: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'media.audio_flinger' died
05-11 15:33:17.928: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'media.player' died
05-11 15:33:17.928: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'media.camera' died
05-11 15:33:17.928: I/ServiceManager(99): service 'media.audio_policy' died
05-11 15:33:17.936: D/FileMonitorService(120): binderDied() 1 0x40918c90, tid 158, calling tid 120
```

Comment: Your service died, either killed by the OS or stopped from your app. Try overriding onDestroy and watch the stack trace.

Comment: Which statement in logcat points to OS stopping my service? Why are other services dieing too?

Comment: android.os.DeadObjectException is thrown, and that means that the object you are calling has died because it's parent process no longer exists. The OS could kill your service for various reasons, try returning STICKY in onCommandStart(), but my first shot would be logging in onDestroy() to see if it really does crash after the service was killed (for whatever reason)

Comment: Thanks, just trying onDestroy now.

Comment: When a crash occurs onDestroy is not called, at least no Log is printed.

Comment: The way i see it, android.net.TrafficStats.getMobileIfaces is calling the dead object not me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is GPS related and it's smooth after few weeks of factory reset then it happens again. So i took a wild guess and thought it has something to do with A-GPS caching.

I use the following code to clear GPS cache after each reboot and it seems to be working.

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.sendExtraCommand(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,"delete_aiding_data", null);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
locationManager.sendExtraCommand("gps", "force_xtra_injection", bundle);
locationManager.sendExtraCommand("gps", "force_time_injection", bundle);
```

This is still not a fix, it's just a workaround to ignore and postpone the problem. The actual problem exist with SM-T111NQ devices and Samsung has yet to provide a fix.

Comment: Got also this terrible SM-T111, same issue. From logcat, I can see the failing PID produces log messages from BatteryService, SensorService, PowerManagerService, Monitor, Watchdog, SignalStrength, GpsLocationProvider and maybe more. But I can confirm it happens only if running my app, which heavily uses GPS. And, from the thread ID, I can confirm Location Service.

Comment: Maybe, we both do a pattern causing this failure (like @fadden pointed out).

Comment: @lef you can try the solution above, clearing gps aid data on regular intervals(once a day or a week) fixed the issue for me.

Comment: There seems to be update to Android 5 Lollipop available. Maybe that could help? http://www.lollipopupdate.xyz/upgrade-update-samsung-galaxy-tab-3-lite-3g-sm-t111-to-5-0-lollipop.html

Answer (score 7):

That's not your app crashing.  That's the Android runtime crashing, and it's taking everything (including your app) with it.

Any time you see a huge pile of services dying, you know that system_server has died.  Some specific logs highlight the failure:

```
05-11 15:33:16.084: A/<unknown>(30963): stack corruption detected: aborted
[...]
05-11 15:33:17.452: D/Zygote(30691): Process 30963 terminated by signal (6)
05-11 15:33:17.452: I/Zygote(30691): Exit zygote because system server (30963) has terminated
```

The first identifies stack corruption of the native system_server heap as the failure cause, the other two identify pid 30963 as system_server.  Signal 6 is SIGABRT, which system_server sent to itself when the corruption was detected.

This is not something you can fix -- there is a bug in the platform, not your app.  My guess is that there's a bit of bad code running in system_server, possibly introduced by the OEM, that is being exercised by your app.  You may be able to work around the problem by changing your app's behavior to not exercise the bug, but without knowing more about the bug that can be difficult.  If there's no update past 4.2.2 for this device then getting a fix for the system from the manufacturer is unlikely.

You might be able to learn a little more by gathering the logs with `adb logcat -v threadtime` to show the thread IDs, and then see which thread reports the corruption.  An `adb shell ps -t` before the crash might give a meaningful label to the thread.  Of course, with native corruption, any thread could stomp on any other thread, but with stack corruption it's more likely that the thread is harming itself.

Comment: I tried running adb commands and saw 2 crashes both give "stack corruption detected: aborted" message from LocationManager (matched the process number between two adb commands you posted). 

Any suggestion what i can do with this information? My app relies heavily on GPS and it seems like LocationManager is causing the problem.

Comment: In both logcat messages i see these before crash: 
05-11 19:42:40.862 12569 12614 D SensorService:  [AR] -12.1 1.8 -0.2

05-11 19:42:40.862 12569 12614 D SensorService: AutoRotationSensor::process: Ar_SensorChanged oldrotation = [3], rotation = [255]

05-11 19:42:40.862 12569 12615 V WindowOrientationListener: Rotation Sensor : x=255.0 

Do you think orientation sensor causing trouble? Or is it just coincidence?

Comment: IIRC, there is OEM-provided code for GPS and the sensors running in system_server. Unfortunately I don't know of an easy way to debug this sort of thing. It sounds like it's GPS-related, but you can't stop using the GPS. There are any number of apps that use GPS without crashing the device, so there may be some pattern to your usage that is triggering the failure.

Comment: This issue is definetely location manager and GPS related. 
I tried disabling rotation sensor but it still crashes.
Any pointers you can give me debug the issue?

Comment: Not really. If something your app is doing is inciting the crash, then changing your app's behavior in small ways might avoid the problem. Make fewer calls, or make calls in a different order. Stack corruption might be due to a buffer overflow, so keep an eye out for anything that could flood a buffer.

Answer (score -1):

It seems sometime time that can not find adb. so please try to reinstall Dalvik machine and adb installer.

Comment: This problem occurs on a real device and also i have no way of reinstalling dalvik machine.